# Too much inception in the query, or is this kosher?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, subquery

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM feesbydate
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(from_date) as the_date FROM (
            SELECT a.* FROM feesbydate a, feesbydate b
            WHERE a.exchFee_ID = 15 AND b.exchFee_ID = 15 
                    AND a.from_date <= b.from_date
                    AND a.id <> b.id AND b.id = 62
            GROUP BY a.id
        ) a) b on from_date < the_date
    WHERE exchFee_ID = 15) c
 WHERE not(isnull(the_date));
```

Basically I have a table that has the following columns:

> id | exch_feeID | from_date | to_date | other irrelevant columns

I want to get all records that have a `from_date` that is **before** a certain `id` (in the example above `62`) and with a certain `exchFee_ID` (in the example above `15`).

The query above works. But as my table grows this might not be the most ideal. Is there a more performant or efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT *
  FROM feesbydate AS f,
       ( SELECT from_date
           FROM feesbydate
          WHERE id = 62
            AND exchFee_ID = 15 ) AS g
 WHERE f.exchFee_ID = 15
   AND f.from_date < g.from_date
```

As long as you can guarantee that every record has a value stored under `from_date` this should be suffice.

Comment: Your query has one extra record that mine **does not** have, why is that?

Comment: Which one would that be? Please post its record set.

Comment: Oh, I see. In your innermost JOIN you are selecting the maximum `from_date` of the rows that have `id`s other than `62`. Then in the outer scope you are excluding this date explicitly with `... b on from_date < the_date`.

Comment: My query on the other hand searches for records with a `from_date` before the one given by the record set with `id = 62`. Hence the additional record.

Comment: So that means my query is **not** correct at all! Wow, how could I have missed that? It seems your query has the info that I need :-D. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

As long as your keys and indexes are sane this is fine. SQL is *for* complexity like this. Don't be afraid to use it.

But if you suspect performance issues, benchmark them first before optimizing them.

Comment: -1 | "SQL is for complexity like this". I don't mean to be offending but this is nonesense.